# What's the free bandwidth given with Google compute engine instances

Tags: google-compute-engine, bandwidth

I'm unable to understand the free bandwidth/traffic allowed in per Google Compute engine instance. I'm using digitalocean and here with every server it provides free bandwidth/transfer e.g with $ 0.015- 1GB/1CPU and 2TB of Transfer is allowed.

Hence is there any free bandwidth per compute instance or google will charge for every bit transferred to/from VM.

Answer (score 3):

As documented on our [Network Pricing](https://cloud.google.com/compute/pricing#network) page, traffic prices depend on the source and destination. There is no "bucket of bits up til x GB" that are free like a cellphone plan or something. Rather certain types of traffic are always free, and other types are charged. For example, anything coming in from the internet. Or, anything to another VM in the same zone (using internal IPs).

If you are in Free Trial, then of course we give you usage credits, so you can use up to that total amount, in dollars, "for free."